# Add a Filter for Date Range option in a list

Tags: date, sharepoint, filter, range

Here is a little background on the task:

My client has a sharepoint site that has a list of data. One of the columns or fields is a date field, this date is entered manually using MM/DD/YY Format.

My client has requested me to add an option where they could filter the columns by a range of dates on the webpart view.

I read this guide: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/sharepoint-list-filtering-by-date-range.aspx and i got it to work, but it seems to be a bit buggy, meaning that sometimes the list will not get filtered by the specified dates..

Another issue with this method is that there is no Submit/Go button.

FROM: [ Text Field ] TO: [ Text Field ] [GO Button]

My client would love to have something like the example above where there are two text fields next to each other and a button that they can click to make the filter activate.

I searched for hours and hours and was not able to find something like this.

Do you guys know of a solution and if so, provide me with a link or guide, on how to achieve this problem? Thanks

**EDIT:**
It seems that there is a Apply Filters Button Web Part that does what i need. I added it and it seems to work Okay. I have to click Apply Filters TWICE in order for it to work.. ***weird huh? is there a fix for that?***

FYI: i followed the guide linked above and just added the apply filters button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed it,

It was because i was adding the date filter web parts to the library itself, and i was supposed to create a page for it and add my web-parts in there.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that'll load the filters on first click for me.

In SPD, under the web part that displays the list items (XsltListViewWebPart), change these two to "True":
 **ClientRender="True"** and **IsClientRender="True"**

Similar issues mentioned in **[this thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/1783694.aspx?ASP%20NET%20Button%20needs%20to%20be%20clicked%20twice)** gave insights to button load sequences and why it doesn't render results on the first click.